# map: ctx.file.dirname.includes('examples')?

Tags: javascript, sass, postcss, postcss-cli

I'm currently building a website using understrap themes. now in the postcss.config.js file I want to know what is this code use for. map: ctx.file.dirname.includes('examples') ?.

Here is the actual code

```html
   'use strict'

module.exports = ctx => {
  return {
    map: ctx.file.dirname.includes('examples') ?
      false :
      {
        inline: false,
        annotation: false,
        sourcesContent: true
      },
    plugins: {
      autoprefixer: {
        cascade: false,
        stylelint: false
       
      },
      "postcss-understrap-palette-generator" : {}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it's evaluating if the example module is existing?

Comment: I think it will evaluate if the directory exists. I try to change the ('examples') to the existing directory what it does is it will not create a sourcemap files after running the postcss CLI.

Comment: Please refer to this forumn . I think this is the answer we're looking for https://wordpress.org/support/topic/module-exports-ctx-return-map-ctx-file-dirname-includescss/